# How to avoid java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException in the case when you iterate through the first element of each array in a two-dimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

I am working on a Markov Chain simulation for a Cloud Computing server which has 4 Servers and each server has 4 VMs.

Server in my case is the array

> {4,1,0}

And **busy VMs** are the first variable of this array, so it is 4.
Now when we have an arrival we check if all servers have 4 VMs busy, if so, we drop the packets so loss variable in my case will be increased, otherwise I will check if the first server has 4 VMs busy, if so the arrival will come to the second server if its VMs are not all busy. Now in the second iteration, I can have a departure and if this is the case the departure may happen to each of the servers which have at least one VMs. I check it using a probability formula but I do not want to enter in detail for that here.

Now I have a problem to solve for the system described above, as below:

At the beginning of simulation, I have a 2D-array

> [{4,1,0},{3,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0}]
>
> // First Iteration

Now I want to check that if for all arrays the first element is 4, then I will increase a variable named to my code as

> loss

Otherwise I will check if the first element of the array is 4, if it is 4 then I will go on and check the second element of the array, if the second element of the array as in my case above is not 4 then I will increase it by 1 and I want to get the result

> [{4,1,0},{4,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0}]

Now in the next 4 iterations "If I always will have arrival packets and no departure" I would like to get the output as below

> [{4,1,0},{4,1,0},{1,1,0},{0,1,0}]
>   [{4,1,0},{4,1,0},{2,1,0},{0,1,0}]
>   [{4,1,0},{4,1,0},{3,1,0},{0,1,0}]
>   [{4,1,0},{4,1,0},{4,1,0},{0,1,0}]

But meanwhile, I still have to check the first variable of the first array and second array since these values due to some other part of my code could be decreased if departure happens.

> //Second Iteration (departure)

So let's say I have in second Iteration a departure, the status of my 2D-array after the first Iteration is

> [{4,1,0},{4,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0}]

Now a departure happens, and let say it happens to the second server and my status will be again as the beginning

> [{4,1,0},{3,1,0},{0,1,0},{0,1,0}]
>
> // Third iteration (Arrival)

Now I have to check the first element of the first array, since it is 4, I can not increment this element and so I have to check the first element of the second array, since it is not 4, I have to increment it by 1.

Now In my java code below, I am running into a **java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException** (which I know what it is), when I check if the first of each element of the arrays is 4, and if it is 4, I have to check it for the second array and so on

Now the second problem is that I have more departure than arrivals when I run my implementation for 100 000 replications (iterations)

I really need some help with that.

```
MainSimulation markovChain= new MainSimulation();

//statistics
int loss=0;
int arrivals=0;
int k=0;
int failures=0;
int departures=0;

//initializations
int numberOfReplications=100000;
int[] currentStateServer1= {4,1,0}; // this means Server 1 is working and all its VMs are busy
int[] currentStateServer2= {3,1,0};
int[] currentStateServer3= {0,1,0};
int[] currentStateServer4= {0,1,0};

int[][] currentState= {currentStateServer1,currentStateServer2,currentStateServer3,currentStateServer4};

for(int i=0;i<numberOfReplications;i++) {

    // generate a random number uniformly distributed between 0.0 and 1.0
    double uniformRandomNumber=randomNumber.nextDouble(); 
    System.out.println("The random number is" +uniformRandomNumber);

    //Arrival
    if (uniformRandomNumber<lambda/markovChain.sum(currentState)){

        System.out.println("We have arrival");
        if(currentState[0][0]==4 && currentState[1][0]==4 && currentState[2][0]==4 &&currentState[3][0]==4) {
            // the system is full, arrivals get lost
            loss++;
        } else {
            /*
             * test the current state 2D array to check if any server have all VMs busy
             *  If yes, check the next server and so on
             */
             for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
                 if(currentState[j][0]==4) {
                     //if true, check the next server if all its VMs are busy
  //Here I have a RunTime error
                     currentState[j][0]=currentState[j+1][0];
                     System.out.println("The currentState is "+currentState[j][0]);
                 } else {
                     /*
                      *  if false, then this server has a free VM and the VM requests will occupy this server
                      *  the state of this server(the first variable) in this case will be increased by one
                      */
                      currentState[j][0] = currentState[j][0]+1;
                  } // close if block, used for checking or incrementing the state of each server   

              } // close for used for checking or incrementing the state of each server to the next one
          } // close the if block which check if the system if full or not
          arrivals++;
      } //close arrival

      //Departure   
      //departure check for the first server
      else if(uniformRandomNumber<(lambda+mu*currentState[0][0])/markovChain.sum(currentState)) {

          departures++;
          currentState[0][0]=currentState[0][0]-1;
      } //close the "check if" departure for first server
         // departure check for the second server
      else if(uniformRandomNumber<(lambda+mu*(currentState[0][0]+currentState[1][0]))/markovChain.sum(currentState)){

          departures++;
          currentState[1][0]=currentState[1][0]-1;
      } //close the "check if" departure occurs for the second server
        // departure check for the third server
      else if(uniformRandomNumber<(lambda+mu*(currentState[0][0]+currentState[1][0]+currentState[2][0]))/markovChain.sum(currentState)) {

          departures++;
          currentState[2][0]=currentState[2][0]-1;
       } //close the "check if" departure occurs for the third server
       else if(uniformRandomNumber<(lambda+mu*(currentState[0][0]+currentState[1][0]+currentState[2][0]+currentState[3][0]))/markovChain.sum(currentState)) {

            departures++;
            currentState[3][0]=currentState[3][0]-1;
        } //close the "check if" departure occurs for the third server
           // close departure

    //When I system.out.println the number of arrivals and departures I have more departures
```

Comment: exactly the same way as you would in a normal array.

Comment: *Server in my case is the array*: and that's your main problem. Stop using arrays to represent objects. Create a Server class, with typed, named fields. Stop using magic numbers to represent a server state (or whatever): use an enum with named constants. And use methods, like `if (server.hasOnlyBusyVMs())`

Comment: Please add your error output for better debugging purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first problem is a combination:
First, you don't need the precheck if any of those 4 servers have a full VM, you are already checking this in your for-loop.

Second, your check if the current state is 4 is super weird. There is no point of reassigning the current state with the following current state:

```
for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
    if(currentState[j][0]==4) {                       
    //Here I have RunTime error
        currentState[j][0]=currentState[j+1][0]; //this is no logical
        System.out.println("The currentState is "+currentState[j][0]);
    }
```

Better do it like this:

```
boolean noLoss=false;
for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
    if(currentState[j][0]==4)
        continue; //if current server has no vms free, chck the next server
    else{
        currentState[j][0]++; //
        arrival++; //the package got assigned to a server, so it arrived
        noLoss=true; //the package was able to arrive to a server
        break; //we don't need to check any other server, since the package arrived
    }
}
if(!noLoss)
    loss++; //the package couldn't find a free server, hence it is a loss
```

these Lines are not needed anymore:

```
if(currentState[0][0]==4 && currentState[1][0]==4 && currentState[2][0]==4 &&currentState[3][0]==4) {
    // the system is full, arrivals get lost
    loss++;
} else{                  
    for(int j=0;j<4;j++) {
        if(currentState[j][0]==4) { 
            currentState[j][0]=currentState[j+1][0];
            System.out.println("The currentState is "+currentState[j][0]);
        }
        else {                
            currentState[j][0] = currentState[j][0]+1;
        } // close if block, used for checking or incrementing the state of each server   
    } // close for used for checking or incrementing the state of each server to the next one
} // close the if block which check if the system if full or not
arrivals++;
```

To your second problem: I can't retrace what exactly your `lambda` and your `markovChain` object is. You need to check the number of arrivals if there is a departure (only arrived packets can departure?). Otherwise, this is totally random (and dependents from your if-statements). So if you get too many departures, it is firstly because you don't include arrivals in your calculations and/or your markovChain is not correct.

**Edit 1**:
If you count an arrived package either way (loss or not loss), then surely you need to put the arrived outside of the for-loop

```
boolean noLoss=false;
for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
    if(currentState[j][0]==4)
        continue; //if current server has no vms free, chck the next server
    else{
        currentState[j][0]++;
        noLoss=true; //the package was able to arrive to a server
        break; //we don't need to check any other server, since the package arrived
    }
}
if(!noLoss)
    loss++; //the package couldn't find a free server, hence it is a loss
arrived++;
```

Comment: thank you for your hint, but I am not sure if your code check the case that when all VMs are busy the arrivals get lost. Maybe I have not explained it good but I want to have losses only when all VMs to each servers are busy

Comment: make a quick debug, First we have noLoss set to false (we assume we won't find any free vm). Then we check the first server, no free vm, then we check the second, no free vm, then the third and finally the fourth. If we haven't gotten any free vm, `noLoss` is still `false`. j is 5, bigger than 4, so we leave the `for` loop and come to the `if(!noLoop)`. `noLoop` is false, so we do `loss++`
if during those 4 checks we find any free vm, we set `noLoss` to true and leave the for-loop

Comment: I debugged it and your code is code, but I should also increment arrivals when all VMs are busy so in your code I guess I should put arrivals++ below loss++ right?

Comment: ah well, yeah I just assumed that arrival is not a loss, I edit my code